# How do the $http service's callback methods notify angular of a model change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following AngularJS controller:

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.phones = {};    

  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.phones = data.splice(0, 5);
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}
```

Using that code (from the angular official tutorial), a template which has bound the `phones` model will be updated to reflect the received JSON response. However, if you wrap the $scope update in a `setTimeout` statement as follows:

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.phones = {};    

  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            $scope.phones = data.splice(0, 5);
        }, 
        5000
    );
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}
```

The template will not be update, the angular code does not seem to pick up the model change in this case.

My question is obvious: why doesn't it work in the second case? How is the angular runtime notified of the model change in the $http callback?

Comment: This is not working because setTimeout does not know anything about angular scope as it is executed outside the angular scope if you want your code to be working you have to use scope.$apply as answered below by joakimbl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use setTimeout you execute the callback function (even if it has no delay) outside the angular framework. If you want to changes within Angular in this function you have to notify Angular by using [`$scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) - like this:

```js
setTimeout(
  function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.phones = data.splice(0, 5);
    }
   },5000);
```

If you have to use setTimeout you should have a look at the [$timout service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout).

Comment: It was purely a question of understanding angular, thanks for your answer!